# Add static content into highchart exported pdf header

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, highcharts

I am using highchart export option for download pdf and i need to add some static content into the highchart header,but i can't have the perfect solution, 
Any one please help me?

[Please click here for the reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYRCK.png)

I need to add the content of the above image into the exported pdf header left side.How to make this? Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

I have updated [add-data-table](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#add-data-table) official example to add static table.
Here I passed two array td1 and td2 one for first column and second column

```
var td1 = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3'];
var td2 = ['text12', 'text22', 'text32'];
```

Code for creating table using render

```
td1.forEach(function(name, i) {
    renderer.text(
        name,
        cellLeft + cellPadding,
        tableTop + (i + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
      )
      .css({
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      })
      .attr({
        align: 'left'
      })
      .add();
  });

  td2.forEach(function(point, row) {

    // Apply the cell text
    renderer.text(
        point,
        cellLeft + colWidth - cellPadding,
        tableTop + (row + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
      )
      .attr({
        align: 'left'
      })
      .add();
  });
};
```

```js
var td1 = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3'];
var td2 = ['text12', 'text22', 'text32'];
/**
 * Create the data table
 */
Highcharts.drawTable = function() {

  // user options
  var tableTop = 0,
    colWidth = 100,
    tableLeft = 20,
    rowHeight = 20,
    cellPadding = 2.5,
    valueDecimals = 1,
    valueSuffix = ' °C';

  // internal variables
  var chart = this,
    series = chart.series,
    renderer = chart.renderer,
    cellLeft = tableLeft;

  // draw category labels
  td1.forEach(function(name, i) {
    renderer.text(
        name,
        cellLeft + cellPadding,
        tableTop + (i + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
      )
      .css({
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      })
      .attr({
        align: 'left'
      })
      .add();
  });

  td2.forEach(function(point, row) {

    // Apply the cell text
    renderer.text(
        point,
        cellLeft + colWidth - cellPadding,
        tableTop + (row + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
      )
      .attr({
        align: 'left'
      })
      .add();


  });


};



var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    height: 600,
    width: 600
  },

  exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
      chart: {
        height: 600,
        marginTop: 110,
        events: {
          load: Highcharts.drawTable
        }
      },
      legend: {
        y: -220
      },
      title: {
        align: 'center',
        y: 90
      },
      credits: {
        position: {
          y: -220
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [1, 2]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/e7qh50ms/) demo